# Require latest pip before installing requirements

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

How can I add a hard requirement for a 20.0.2+ pip in requirements.txt?

I have seen some environments that fail to install PyQt5 when pip is around 19.x

currently my requirements.txt is setup as

```sh
pip>=20.0.2
PyQt5
fbs
```

this updates pip no problem but uses the same pip version to install PyQt5 and fbs, which I understand is intended behaviour.

Comment: You can do this as documentation, not as executable requirement.

Comment: well thats what i already did, thanks for answering!